# $x'(t)=f(x(t))=kx(t)(1-x(t)), k>0$ a real number, find $x''(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following question :

> Given : $x'(t)=f(x(t))=kx(t)(1-x(t)), k>0$ a real number, find $x''(t).$

I'm a bit confused from this question.

I know that $x''(t)=(f(x(t))'=f'(x(t))\,x'(t).$

We know that $x'(t)=kx(t)(1-x(t))$ and 
$$f'(x(t))=x''(t)=(kx(t)(1-x(t)))'=(x'(t)(1-x(t))+(-x'(t)(kx(t)))).$$

I get something with $(x(t))^2$ from this, while the answer from the book is $x''(t)=f'(x)=k(1-2x(t)).$

I don't see what I'm missing.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I don't think $f'(x(t))=x'(t).$

Comment: I think you dropped the $k$'s from your $f'(x(t))$ calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
\begin{align*}
x'&=kx(1-x)\\
x''&=kx'(1-x)-kxx'\\
&=kx'-kxx'-kxx'\\
&=kx'-2kxx'\\
&=kx'(1-2x)\\
&=k\underbrace{kx(1-x)}_{x'}(1-2x)\\
&=k^2x(1-x)(1-2x).
\end{align*}
The book's answer doesn't look right to me. What's missing is that, in order to find $x''(t),$ you actually have to compute $f'(x(t))\,x'(t),$ not just $f'(x),$ like the book's answer has. Their answer is a partial answer.

Incidentally, you can solve the original ODE exactly. Mathematica yields
$$x(t)=\frac{e^{k t}}{e^{c_1}+e^{k t}}. $$

Answer (score 2):

In fact you have calculated $f'(x(t))$ in a wrong way. This expression means first differentiating $f(u)=ku(1-u)$ with respect to $u$ and then substituting $u=x(t)$. Therefore$$f'(x(t))=k-2kx(t)$$

Comment: I don't think the OP is quite so far off. If he fixed the missing $k$'s, he'd be on the right track.

Comment: You are right just for the kind of $f(x)$ defined here. In fact the differentiation brings the OP quite off the correct way...

Comment: To find $x'',$ though, you'd have to multiply the $f'(x(t))$ that you have by $x'(t)$ to complete the Chain Rule application.

Comment: I just fixed up the wrong term....